# error in attribute extended from trait in scala

Tags: java, scala

i am using scala and i have a trait with an attribute "name" i extended this trait in Userclass where i am accessing the attribute
 when i tried to declare name in the trait like this

```
val name : String
```

it gave error in child class that child class ha unimplemented member 
but when i tried

```
val name : String = ""
```

it just worked fine
please tell me the difference and reason why it was not working before and why it worked after the modification

Comment: Why do u use val with className? u can just val name = 'Joe' and name will String, for typing u should use var

Comment: Maybe you should show the actual trait and extending class.

Comment: Well you actually have to provide an implementation of `name` in `UserClass`  if you haven't done so in the trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this:

```
trait hasName {
  val name : String
}

class Person extends hasName
```

A trait is, by nature, `abstract`, which means that it allowed to have unimplemented methods.  In effect, what the `trait` is declaring is this:

> All classes extending `hasName` are *guaranteed* to have a `val name : String` instance variable.  What is *in* that variable is dependent on the actual child class

In the case above, your code is expanded to:

```
trait hasName {
  val name : String = ???
}
```

where the `???` means essentially that the particular 'function' is unimplemented.

After your modification:

```
trait hasName {
  val name : String
}

class Person extends hasName {val name : String = ""}
```

The extending class, `Person` *overrides* the `hasName` trait's implementation, or in this case, lack thereof, with its own implementation.

Alternatively, if you do:

```
trait hasName {
  val name : String = ""
}
```

You are adding an implementation to `hasName`, so every child class will, by default, have that implementation.

Comment: please tell me what is happening in memory when i used these two approaches?
why first approach did not work?
was it not referring to anything in the memory?

Comment: There is in fact nothing 'happening in memory' in this case. At compile time, `extends hasName` indicates that your user class will have an implementation of `val name : String`, but the compiler finds no such implementation and hence does not compile.